# How would I echo the genres out of this array?

Tags: php

I am trying to display the movie genres with echo...so horror, action, and thriller will show up like this

horror
action
thriller

I know I will need break points in between but I cannot figure out how to get the keys of these arrays to print.

```
<?php
        $movies = array (
         "horror"=>array (
         "Paranormal Activity"=> array (
         "Katie Featherston",
         "Kathryn Newton"
         ),
         "The Ring"=> array (
         "Naomi Watts",
         "Brian Cox"
         ),
         "Sleepy Hollow"=> array(
         "Johhny Depp",
         "Christina Ricci"
         )
         ),
         "action" => array (
         "The Tourist"=> array (
         "Johnny Depp",
         "Angelina Jolie"
         ),
         "Public Enemies"=> array (
         "Johnny Depp", "Christian Bale"
         ),
         "The Dark Knight Rises"=> array (
         "Christian Bale",
         "Tom Hardy"
         ),
         "Salt"=> array (
         "Angelina Jolie"
         )
         ),
         "thriller"=> array (
         "Inception"=> array(
         "Leornardio Dicaprio",
         "Tom Hardy"
         ),
         "Changeling" => array(
         "Angelina Jolie"
         ),
         "The Game"=> array(
         "Michael Douglas",
         "Sean Penn"
         )
         )
        );

        foreach ($movies as $x)
        {
            echo $x;
            echo "</br>";
        }
```

edited

```
foreach ($movies as $key=>$x)
        {
            echo $key;
            echo "</br>";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: In your foreach try this `foreach($movies as $key=>$x){...}` and then echo your $key. EDIT: had to change part of my comment. Brain skipped a beat.

Comment: shouldn't he/she echo $key instead?

Comment: @Dominique I edited my comment right before yours showed up for me. My brain had the dumb for a moment.

Comment: I will test it and let you all know

Comment: @AndrewHotovy You did answer the question, so ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

While the preceding answer works, you could also do the following if you wanted to have code that was a bit more self-documenting:

```
<?php
$keys = array_keys( $movies );
foreach ( $keys as $genre ) {
    echo $genre,"\n";
}
```